# ElasticPress is (aparently) messing my wordpress queries

Tags: php, wordpress, elasticsearch, elasticpress

I recently installed ElasticPress on my woocommerce store, and it's working fine -- the product page is showing normally, and the search bar is working fine with the new elastic capabilities. However, when I try to use the product filters, nothing shows up, the query simply doesn't work. If I deactivate Elasticpress, however, the filters work normally. This is the query:

[Codeshare.io link](https://codeshare.io/GAwO4x) for better readability

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $wp_query;

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'tpk_archive_query' );

function tpk_archive_query( $q ){

    if($_GET['js'] == 'y') {
        $cat = explode(',', esc_attr($_GET['categorias']));
        $a = explode(',', esc_attr($_GET['artistas']));
        $ta = explode(',', esc_attr($_GET['tamanhos']));
        $c = explode(',', esc_attr($_GET['colecoes']));
        $t = explode(',', esc_attr($_GET['tags']));
        $preco = explode(',', esc_attr($_GET['preco']));
        $operador = strtoupper(esc_attr($_GET['op']));
        $orderby = explode('-', esc_attr($_GET['orderby']));
    } else {
        $cat = esc_attr($_GET['cat']);
        $a = esc_attr($_GET['a']);
        $ta = esc_attr($_GET['ta']);
        $c = esc_attr($_GET['c']);
        $t = esc_attr($_GET['t']);
    }



    if((esc_attr($_GET['orderby']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['orderby'])))) {

        if($orderby[0] == 'preco') {

            $q->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
            $q->set('meta_key', '_price');
            $q->set('order', $orderby[1]);

        } else {

            $q->set('orderby', $orderby[0]);
            $q->set('order', $orderby[1]);

        }

    }



    $args = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
    ];

    if((esc_attr($_GET['cat']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['cat'])))) {
        
        $category = [
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $cat,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ];

        array_push($args, $category);
    } elseif(esc_attr($_GET['categorias']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['categorias']))) {

        if(in_array('kits', $cat)) {

            $categorias = ['relation' => 'OR',];

            foreach ($cat as $cate) {

                if($cate != 'kits') {

                    $kitCat = 'kits-' . $cate;

                    $cate = [$cate, $kitCat];

                    $pima = [
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $cate,
                        'operator' => 'IN'
                    ];
                    
                    array_push($categorias, $pima);

                }

            }

        } else {

            $categorias = [
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $cat,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ];

        }

        array_push($args, $categorias);

    }

    if((esc_attr($_GET['a']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['a']))) || (esc_attr($_GET['artistas']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['artistas'])))) {
        $artistas = [
            'taxonomy' => 'autor',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $a,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ];

        array_push($args, $artistas);
    }

    if((esc_attr($_GET['ta']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['ta']))) || (esc_attr($_GET['tamanhos']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['tamanhos'])))) {
        $tamanho = [
            'taxonomy' => 'tamanho',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $ta,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ];

        array_push($args, $tamanho);
    }

    if((esc_attr($_GET['c']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['c']))) || (esc_attr($_GET['colecoes']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['colecoes'])))) {
        $colecao = [
            'taxonomy' => 'colecao',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $c,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ];

        array_push($args, $colecao);
    }

    if((esc_attr($_GET['t']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['t']))) || (esc_attr($_GET['tags']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['tags'])))) {
        
        if(!$operador) {
            $operador = 'OR';
        }
        $tags = ['relation' => $operador,];

        foreach ($t as $tag) {
            $poma = [
                'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $tag,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ];
            
            array_push($tags, $poma);
        }

        array_push($args, $tags);
    }

    $q->set('tax_query', $args);

    if((esc_attr($_GET['preco']) && !empty(esc_attr($_GET['preco'])))) {

        $min_price = $preco[0];
        $max_price = $preco[1];

        $q->set('meta_query', [
            [
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => [$min_price, $max_price],
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            ]
        ]);

    }

}
```

I tried using WP Marvelous Debug to see if there were any errors happening during the query, and it didn't point at anything different. The only "errors" it pointed out were [these undefined indexes](https://i.ibb.co/dp3zhsR/image.png), which I don't belive have anything to do with the problem, because they happen with or without Elastic.

Do I have to write my queries in an elastic-specific syntax? I spent the last two days trying to fix this and I really have no idea what to do.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**---EDIT---**

This is the generated query without any filters active (just the default woocommerce query, which works without any problems):

```
{
"query": {
    "post_type": "product"
},
"query_vars": {
    "post_type": "product",
    "error": "",
    "m": "",
    "p": 0,
    "post_parent": "",
    "subpost": "",
    "subpost_id": "",
    "attachment": "",
    "attachment_id": 0,
    "name": "",
    "pagename": "",
    "page_id": 0,
    "second": "",
    "minute": "",
    "hour": "",
    "day": 0,
    "monthnum": 0,
    "year": 0,
    "w": 0,
    "category_name": "",
    "tag": "",
    "cat": "",
    "tag_id": "",
    "author": "",
    "author_name": "",
    "feed": "",
    "tb": "",
    "paged": 0,
    "meta_key": "",
    "meta_value": "",
    "preview": "",
    "s": "",
    "sentence": "",
    "title": "",
    "fields": "",
    "menu_order": "",
    "embed": "",
    "category__in": [],
    "category__not_in": [],
    "category__and": [],
    "post__in": [],
    "post__not_in": [],
    "post_name__in": [],
    "tag__in": [],
    "tag__not_in": [],
    "tag__and": [],
    "tag_slug__in": [],
    "tag_slug__and": [],
    "post_parent__in": [],
    "post_parent__not_in": [],
    "author__in": [],
    "author__not_in": [],
    "orderby": "popularity",
    "order": "ASC",
    "meta_query": [],
    "tax_query": {
    "relation": "AND"
    },
    "wc_query": "product_query",
    "posts_per_page": 48
},
"tax_query": {
    "queries": [],
    "relation": "AND",
    "queried_terms": [],
    "primary_table": null,
    "primary_id_column": null
},
"meta_query": false,
"date_query": false,
"post_count": 0,
"current_post": -1,
"in_the_loop": false,
"comment_count": 0,
"current_comment": -1,
"found_posts": 0,
"max_num_pages": 0,
"max_num_comment_pages": 0,
"is_single": false,
"is_preview": false,
"is_page": false,
"is_archive": true,
"is_date": false,
"is_year": false,
"is_month": false,
"is_day": false,
"is_time": false,
"is_author": false,
"is_category": false,
"is_tag": false,
"is_tax": false,
"is_search": false,
"is_feed": false,
"is_comment_feed": false,
"is_trackback": false,
"is_home": false,
"is_privacy_policy": false,
"is_404": false,
"is_embed": false,
"is_paged": false,
"is_admin": false,
"is_attachment": false,
"is_singular": false,
"is_robots": false,
"is_favicon": false,
"is_posts_page": false,
"is_post_type_archive": true,
"thumbnails_cached": false
}
```

And this is the generated query when I set the "autor" filter as "Arcane Minis", and the "orderby" to "popularity":

```
{
"query": {
    "orderby": "",
    "post_type": "product"
},
"query_vars": {
    "orderby": "popularity",
    "post_type": "product",
    "error": "",
    "m": "",
    "p": 0,
    "post_parent": "",
    "subpost": "",
    "subpost_id": "",
    "attachment": "",
    "attachment_id": 0,
    "name": "",
    "pagename": "",
    "page_id": 0,
    "second": "",
    "minute": "",
    "hour": "",
    "day": 0,
    "monthnum": 0,
    "year": 0,
    "w": 0,
    "category_name": "",
    "tag": "",
    "cat": "",
    "tag_id": "",
    "author": "",
    "author_name": "",
    "feed": "",
    "tb": "",
    "paged": 0,
    "meta_key": "",
    "meta_value": "",
    "preview": "",
    "s": "",
    "sentence": "",
    "title": "",
    "fields": "",
    "menu_order": "",
    "embed": "",
    "category__in": [],
    "category__not_in": [],
    "category__and": [],
    "post__in": [],
    "post__not_in": [],
    "post_name__in": [],
    "tag__in": [],
    "tag__not_in": [],
    "tag__and": [],
    "tag_slug__in": [],
    "tag_slug__and": [],
    "post_parent__in": [],
    "post_parent__not_in": [],
    "author__in": [],
    "author__not_in": [],
    "order": "ASC",
    "meta_query": [],
    "tax_query": {
    "0": {
        "taxonomy": "autor",
        "field": "slug",
        "terms": [
        "arcane-minis"
        ],
        "operator": "IN"
    },
    "relation": "AND"
    },
    "wc_query": "product_query",
    "posts_per_page": 48
},
"tax_query": {
    "queries": [],
    "relation": "AND",
    "queried_terms": [],
    "primary_table": null,
    "primary_id_column": null
},
"meta_query": false,
"date_query": false,
"post_count": 0,
"current_post": -1,
"in_the_loop": false,
"comment_count": 0,
"current_comment": -1,
"found_posts": 0,
"max_num_pages": 0,
"max_num_comment_pages": 0,
"is_single": false,
"is_preview": false,
"is_page": false,
"is_archive": true,
"is_date": false,
"is_year": false,
"is_month": false,
"is_day": false,
"is_time": false,
"is_author": false,
"is_category": false,
"is_tag": false,
"is_tax": false,
"is_search": false,
"is_feed": false,
"is_comment_feed": false,
"is_trackback": false,
"is_home": false,
"is_privacy_policy": false,
"is_404": false,
"is_embed": false,
"is_paged": false,
"is_admin": false,
"is_attachment": false,
"is_singular": false,
"is_robots": false,
"is_favicon": false,
"is_posts_page": false,
"is_post_type_archive": true,
"thumbnails_cached": false
}
```

And lastly, this is the filtered query without elastic press:

```
{
"query": {
    "orderby": "",
    "post_type": "product"
},
"query_vars": {
    "orderby": "popularity",
    "post_type": "product",
    "error": "",
    "m": "",
    "p": 0,
    "post_parent": "",
    "subpost": "",
    "subpost_id": "",
    "attachment": "",
    "attachment_id": 0,
    "name": "",
    "pagename": "",
    "page_id": 0,
    "second": "",
    "minute": "",
    "hour": "",
    "day": 0,
    "monthnum": 0,
    "year": 0,
    "w": 0,
    "category_name": "",
    "tag": "",
    "cat": "",
    "tag_id": "",
    "author": "",
    "author_name": "",
    "feed": "",
    "tb": "",
    "paged": 0,
    "meta_key": "",
    "meta_value": "",
    "preview": "",
    "s": "",
    "sentence": "",
    "title": "",
    "fields": "",
    "menu_order": "",
    "embed": "",
    "category__in": [],
    "category__not_in": [],
    "category__and": [],
    "post__in": [],
    "post__not_in": [],
    "post_name__in": [],
    "tag__in": [],
    "tag__not_in": [],
    "tag__and": [],
    "tag_slug__in": [],
    "tag_slug__and": [],
    "post_parent__in": [],
    "post_parent__not_in": [],
    "author__in": [],
    "author__not_in": [],
    "order": "ASC",
    "meta_query": [],
    "tax_query": {
    "0": {
        "taxonomy": "autor",
        "field": "slug",
        "terms": [
        "arcane-minis"
        ],
        "operator": "IN"
    },
    "relation": "AND"
    },
    "wc_query": "product_query",
    "posts_per_page": 48
},
"tax_query": {
    "queries": [],
    "relation": "AND",
    "queried_terms": [],
    "primary_table": null,
    "primary_id_column": null
},
"meta_query": false,
"date_query": false,
"post_count": 0,
"current_post": -1,
"in_the_loop": false,
"comment_count": 0,
"current_comment": -1,
"found_posts": 0,
"max_num_pages": 0,
"max_num_comment_pages": 0,
"is_single": false,
"is_preview": false,
"is_page": false,
"is_archive": true,
"is_date": false,
"is_year": false,
"is_month": false,
"is_day": false,
"is_time": false,
"is_author": false,
"is_category": false,
"is_tag": false,
"is_tax": false,
"is_search": false,
"is_feed": false,
"is_comment_feed": false,
"is_trackback": false,
"is_home": false,
"is_privacy_policy": false,
"is_404": false,
"is_embed": false,
"is_paged": false,
"is_admin": false,
"is_attachment": false,
"is_singular": false,
"is_robots": false,
"is_favicon": false,
"is_posts_page": false,
"is_post_type_archive": true,
"thumbnails_cached": false
}
```

Comment: Would it be feasible to dump the final **JSON query** (`json_encode($q)`) before it gets sent to ES?

Comment: @JoeSorocin excuse my ignorance, but I'm not very well versed in PHP (I'm a UX designer), so if you could elaborate on your answer I would be very thankful. Do you mean I should just add `json_encode($q)` at the end of the function?

Comment: No worries. I meant that we need to see the actual, final Elasticsearch query in order to assess this. So yes -- add that statement to the end of the function a edit your question with the response.

Comment: @JoeSorocin Awesome, thanks. I edited the question with the query args for the default woocommerce query, and my filtered query.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was gonna be a query I can work with but I'm not familiar w/ this syntax/elasticpress.